# How to search Index 1, Index 2 and Index 3 pages globally from header searchbox?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a global search box in a header which is `header.html` page

header.html

```
 <div class="col-md-4" style="float:right; margin-right:0px;">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch" />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have headerController.js

```
  function headerController($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
        var vm = this;


    }
```

Index1.html

This is index 1 page. Index 1 is so beautiful

Index2.html

This is index 2 page. Index 2 is so wonderful

Index 3.html

This is index 3 page. Index 3 is so cute

I am developing this using angularjs so when I search for `beautiful` keyword it should show me a popup(not alert) that beautiful word is in Index 1 page. If I search for word `wonderful` it should show me in a popup(not alert) that wonderful is in index 2 page. I have tried other static search types which points to an ng-repeat list of elements to filter and search. But  how can I achieve this way

I tried to look at this sample, but I am getting an error

http://plnkr.co/edit/FMRTTbxdNv0pGSYpfwve?p=preview

Error is

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams%20%3C-%20searchResultsController
    at angular.js:99
    at angular.js:4891
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:5051)
    at angular.js:4896
    at d (angular.js:5051)
    at e (angular.js:5076)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5120)
    at angular.js:11175
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at angular.js:1364 "<div class="well ng-scope" ui-view="">"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your SearchResultsController (untested):

```
$scope.results = [];

$http.get(url1).then(function(result){if(result.data.contains($scope.query)) $scope.results.push("url1")});

$http.get(url2).then(function(result){if(result.data.contains($scope.query)) $scope.results.push("url2")});

$http.get(url3).then(function(result){if(result.data.contains($scope.query)) $scope.results.push("url3")});
```

Then in your html page:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results">Found in: {{result}}</div>
```

Comment: Is there a without creating three lines of code of same logic.

Comment: It would be better if you could help to provide more clearly